# What is the point of this monadic law?

Tags: scala, functional-programming, monads

I am reading an [article](http://james-iry.blogspot.co.il/2007/10/monads-are-elephants-part-3.html) about "monadic laws". The first law the article mentions is:

```
m map f ≡ m flatMap {x => unit(f(x))}
```

For Scala `Option` it means:

```
option map f ≡ option flatMap {x => Option(f(x))}
```

Now I wonder what the law point is. Why is the law important ? What if Scala `Option` does not obey this law ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it does not obey the monad laws it's not a monad. That's actually why the `unit` of `Option` is `Some.apply` and not `Option.apply`. Just look at this case:

```
scala> val f = (x: Int) => null

scala> (option map f) == (option flatMap {x => Option(f(x))})
res4: Boolean = false
```

The particular law here just says, that `map` is basically a composition of `flatMap` and `unit`

Comment: Thank you ! I still wonder why it's important that Option will be a monad. What's wrong with non-monadic Option?

Comment: It just means that it has a certain behaviour. For example being a monad is a pre-requisite for usage in a for-comprehension. However scala does not enforce the laws. That is why `Try` - which is not a monad - can still be used in for-comprehensions.

Comment: Thanks. Why being a monad is a pre-prequisite for for-comprehension ? What is wrong with `Try` in for-comprehension ?

Comment: `Try` violates left identity. As for for-comprehensions, there are several good answers to that question all over the internet.

Comment: I will try to find the answers. Thanks.

Comment: @Michael There are a whole bunch of useful computations that involve **monads in general** rather than a specific monad, such as `Option`. These computations rely on the monad laws for their correctness. If you made `Option` operate slightly differently such that it wasn't a monad, then you've still got your (variant of) `Option`. But you wouldn't get all the *extra* generic monad functionality (such as the ability to write for-comprehensions) wouldn't apply.

Comment: Much of the point of monads in programming is code reuse; there are many families of useful operations that can be defined on a huge variety of different types that turn out to be just special cases of the same generic operation once you recognise that the huge variety of different types are all instances of monads. As such (in programming communities where the use of monads is common) many of these operations are already written for you before you even sit down to begin writing your program.

Comment: @Ben Thank you. Could you give an example how violating monadic laws by `flatMap` of some `A[T]` prevents using it in for-comprehension ?

Comment: It would be cool to see the following example: Let `A[T]` defines `flatMap(f:T=>A[T]):A[T] = {...}`. Let the `flatMap` violates certain monadic law. Let's write for-comprehension with `A[T]` now. While Scala does allow such for-comprehension it is broken in this and that.