# Implementing Option#unit

Tags: scala

When implementing `Option#unit`:

`override def unit[A](a: => A): Option[A] = ...`

is there any difference between these 2?

`Some(a)`

or

`Option[A](a)`

Or perhaps the `Option[A]` is unnecessary given the specified return type of `Option[A]`?

Comment: You should make it clear when you're asking about types not part of the Scala Standard Library. This does not appear to be part of it. In particular, Scala's `Option` does not define a `type` projection named `unit`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are trying to make `Option` a monad (judging from the method name), then `Some(a)` is the only version which follows the monad laws. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/20125955/9204

Answer (score 6):

It depends on implementation of `Option` and `Some`. In standart scala, `Option(a)` gives you additional null checking and can return None if `a` evaluates to `null`.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful answer, Sergey. I voted you up, but chose Alexey's answer since I was, in fact, asking about the Option Monad.